# Why does running afconvert result in error -43

Tags: terminal, audio, error

I am trying to use afconvert to convert a .mp3 to .m4r. I am entering the following:

```
afconvert -f m4af -d aac -o input.mp3 tone.m4r
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
Error: Couldn't open input file (-43)
```

I am in the directory of the input file. Could someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `-o` flag, I think. You are specifying `input.mp3` as an output file, and then `tone.m4r` becomes the input file. See the output of `afconvert -h`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run `afconvert -f m4af -d aac -o output.aac input.mp3` and it worked perfectly. And according to the man page, it probably isn't beneficial or necessary to use the `-o` flag, just `afconvert -f m4af -d aac input.mp3 output.aac` would be fine also.

Have you checked the permissions? I tried to `chmod 000 input.mp3` the file and subsequently rerun your command and it returned the same error. Try to run `file input.mp3` and see if other Unix utilities can read that file. If so, I guess the problem is just that the error description from afconvert is not clear enough. And its man page seems to be badly written.